# NextJS basePath does not work on css url()

Tags: css, next.js

### my code

public folder:

```
public
 └ images   
   └ paper-light.png
```

next.config.js:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  nextConfig.basePath = '/blog';
  nextConfig.assetPrefix = '/blog';
}

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

global.css:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('/images/paper-light.png');
}
```

### out code

expected global.css:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('/blog/images/paper-light.png');
}
```

actual result global.css

```css
body {
  background-image: url('/images/paper-light.png');
}
```

How can I fix it to expected?